# google-script getRange() stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

the following lines worked fine with no errors until this morning when it seems to have changed behaviour.

```
var update_row = stockSheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
var stock_line_clear_E = stockSheet.getRange("E:G" + update_row);
```

Now, whilst still selecting column `E` to `G` the value of `update_row` is being ignored and ALL rows are being reset by the `setValue(")` that follows.

I have changed it to three individual lines for the range but this seems wrong.  Anyone now why this would work for months then change?  API update is what I am thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear about what cells you want selected for `stock_line_clear_E`, so here are some options:

- If you wanted to select the cells in columns `E` to `G` in only one row, use:

  ```
  var stock_line_clear_E = stockSheet.getRange("E" + update_row + ":G" + update_row);
  ```

  This is the range implied by the name of your variable.
- If you wanted all rows from 1 to update_row, use:

  ```
  var stock_line_clear_E = stockSheet.getRange("E1:G" + update_row);
  ```

  This is equivalent to `"E:G<update_row>"`, which is what your code was previously building.

There's definitely some bug with interpretation of A1 Notation, though. Playing in a spreadsheet, you can see that `"E:G"`, `"E5:G7"`, and '"E1:G7"' all work as expected, but `"E:G7"` does not.

[image: Bad sheet happening]

In the debugger, we can confirm that the requested range is not what is returned.

[image: More bad sheet.]

**Edit:** Visit and star [Issue 3422](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3422).

Comment: Thanks that gives the answer as I am looking for it.  Using my previous code E:G + update_row was giving me for example E5 F5 G5 but as I say stopped.  Will visit and star the issue log. But at least I can continue.